# How to prevent scroll wheel from changing the selected item of comobox in gnome?

Tags: gnome, gnome3

Scroll wheel changes the selected item of combobox when a cursor is above it, is there any way to disable this behaviour?

Comment: Is disabling the scroll wheel completely an acceptable solution? Otherwise I see no easy way short of modifying and recompiling the gnome widget libraries.